# How to interrupt a 3V circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-motor, motor-controller

I've got a toy train that runs on two batteries (3V). What I am trying to do is to stop the train when it enters the station for a couple of seconds and then let it commence on its journey. The way I was trying to do this is by using an op amp comparator where the inverting input is connected to an IR diode and the reference to a potentiometer. At the train station, there is an IR emitter, which hits the photodiode on the train when it enters. So far so good, all goes well and I can detect a switch from ~1.7V to 0V at the output of the op amp when this happens. The next step is now to interrupt the power supply between battery and train. The train consumes ~300 mA. This is what I tried:

1. PN2222A transistor: the 20 mA coming out of the output are not enough to put the transistor into saturation.
2. TIP120: Not sure why this is not working. When I connect the train, the voltage between collector and Vcc is very low and the train is not running.
3. Relay: I didn't find a relay that I can switch with the 20 mA at 1.7V that I've got.
4. MOSFET: Same. Just didn't find one that seems to match the specs.

So experts out there: any idea how I could stop my train.

Another side question: Why do I only get 1.7V out of my comparator? I thought that I get Vcc, which is 3V in my case?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: is the train engine self contained?

Comment: Are you using an opamp or comparator - they are not the same. What part number is it?

Comment: Please show a schematic diagram of your circuit.

Comment: @jsotola: yes, the engine is self contained.

Comment: @SimonFitch: I'm using the OpAmp LM358N.

Comment: @PeterBennett: I added a diagram to my post. J1 is the train engine. J3 the potentiometer.

Comment: you could also use a reed switch in the locomotive and a magnet at the train station to detect the train arrival

Answer (score 2):

You've made life a little harder for yourself with that LM358, I'm afraid. It may be used as a comparator, but it's not a comparator, and the usual benefits you get from comparators are lost to you here.

The first big problem you have is that with a 3V supply it's working right on the very edge of its abilities. It isn't going to work well (or at all) if the voltage drops below 3V.

The second is that even if it does work, its output will never reach Vcc, or even get close. The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) isn't very clear on this, but it is normal behaviour for this device's output to reach up to about 1.5V from Vcc, but rarely more.

You'll certainly have trouble saturating the 2N2222 with the output of the LM358, so your idea of using the TIP120 is good. Since you get 1.7V out of your opamp, you should be able to use a TIP120, which requires 1.4V at its base to saturate. Also, with a current gain of over 1000, the TIP120 will require only 300µA base current, which will not load the opamp much at all.

However, you will have take care not to overload the opamp output, which is already struggling to lift its output to 1.7V. To guarantee that we saturate the TIP120, we should aim for about 600µA base current, and we'll have to take great care with the base resistor to achieve this. The difference between 1.7V and 1.4V is really small, and doesn't give us much room to maneuver:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flGOGm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I calculate R1 like this:

$$ V_{R1} = 1.7V - 1.4V = 0.3V $$

$$ R_1 = \frac{V_{R1}}{I_{R1}} = \frac{0.3V}{600 \mu A} = 500\Omega $$

It's quite a bit smaller than you see most of the time in such situations, but that's because usually we have more like 5V work with, not 0.3V.

Give your TIP120 another chance, with a 470Ω base resistor, and see how that goes. It's possible that you will you need to use a comparator, like the LM393 which is much better suited to this job, and works down to 2V. I will be happy to cover that in this answer if you still have problems.

##### Edit 1: Sample configurations with LM393

Controlling power at low voltages is hard, because everythings "drops" a voltage which is significant compared to the 3V power supply. You're already victim of this; your TIP120 has \$V_{CE} = 0.25V\$. You seem to have three options. BJT pair, MOSFET, BJT + relay. I admit it was difficult to find components that mitigate this issue of "lost voltage".

The relay is by far the best idea, in this respect, with contact resistances under 0.1Ω. It obviously needs a coil that operates at 3V, possible slightly less for low battery scenarios. Coil current will be around 50mA, which will still require a transistor to provide.

The MOSFET approach comes in a close second. You are looking for a very low gate threshold voltage (\$V_{GS(TH)} < 1.5V\$), and simultaneously a very low drain-source resistance (\$R_{DS(ON)} < 0.5\Omega)\$. The best I could find was the [VN3205](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/VN3205-N-Channel-Enhancement-Mode-Vertical-DMOS-FET-Data-Sheet-20005995A.pdf), but I have no idea how easy it will be for you to obtain. There must be others with similar properties.

If you use bipolar junction transistors, the best approach is a combination of PNP + NPN to minimise \$V_{CE}\$ and maximise current gain. A darlington pair (like the TIP120) is probably not be very useful at this low voltage.

From here on, I'll assume you are using a proper comparator, the LM393, instead of an opamp, the reason being that the way you connect its output to the transistor is going to be different from how you would with an opamp. I'll explain that in a moment, but for now my diagrams will assume an LM393.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi7IiT.png)</sup>

The LM393 (and most other comparators) have [open-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) outputs. That means they can "pull" their output voltages downwards, but they must rely on some external current source, like a resistor, to pull the output high. That's why you see all three circuits A, B and C have resistor R1 in that role.

###### Circuit A

The output of the LM393 is able to pull downwards quite hard, and circuit A takes advantage of this property. Notice how the relay is connected in such a way as to switch *on* the motor when coil current is *off*! In other words, pay careful attention to my use of the normally-closed (N.C.) contacts of the relay. This is because I want coil current to flow only while the motor is off. When the motor is running, which is presumably most of the time, there is no coil current wasting battery energy. This behaviour requires a single pole, double throw (SPDT) relay. The comparator output must be *high* to switch the motor *on*.

###### Circuit B

This is clearly the simplest approach. The downside is the (possibly) difficult to source MOSFET. As I mentioned, the choice of MOSFET here is critical. Here, the LM393 output must be *high* to switch the motor *on*.

###### Circuit C

I control Q1 state with a very low current output from the comparator, but when it's on, Q1 pulls down quite hard. It that state, R2's low value means that it sinks 10mA or so from Q2's base, easily enough to fully saturate Q2, and obtain the lowest possible \$V_{CE}\$ from Q2. Again the comparator output must be *high* to switch the motor *on*.

Comment: thank you so much, I learned a lot! Unfortunately, it's still not working yet, but it's looking much better. The voltage at the motor is now 2.5V (as opposed to almost 0V before). I have a feeling that the missing diode also played a role. I'll buy an LM393 and will try this. Won't complain about some advice how to wire this ;-).

Comment: @Mildred, I added some ideas about how to use different components and configurations with the LM393 comparator.

Comment: @Mildred, the missing diode did not have anything to do with the low motor voltage. It's only there to protect the transistor from anything nasty that the motor throws at it. Low motor voltage is due entirely to the transistor being far from "on" and saturated.

Comment: thank you so much. I'll try all three and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It took me a while, but @SimonFitch, I managed to try all three options. A) is just kind of working. The train doesn't re-start spontaneously, but with a bit of luck it's actually working. B) was the worst. Just didn't get it to work. C) worked sometimes, not as well as A) though.

Comment: Now you've have some time to play with them, you should look at hysteresis, which will help create sharp and steady switching. Do a bit of research into "schmitt triggers" using comparators, and I'll update the answer with an example that could help. It would help me to know the circuitry you use to get a signal on the photodiode side. Then we can maybe find a way to improve its behaviour.